# Подсветка SQL запросов Pycharm

Tags: sql, pycharm

В связи с чем во второй функции `SQL` вызов подсвечен корректно, а в первой подсвечен как обычная строка? Или как можно принудительно определить строку как `SQL` вызов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Помимо визуальной подсветки во второй функции работают подсказки при редактировании запроса, а в первой никаких подсказок не вылазит

Comment: PyCharm бесплатный? По-моему, в нем поддержки SQL почти нет, в отличии от платной версии

Comment: Ну видимая разница - присвоение.

Comment: Пробуйте на строке нажать Alt-Enter -> Inject Language (или как-то так), дальше выбираете диалект SQL.

Comment: Вот такой пункт меню должен быть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAh0l.png (скрин из IDEA, но в PyCharm должно быть аналогично)

Comment: @gil9red нет, платная версия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следуя советом из комментариев, удалось принудительно настроить подсветку

Шаг 1: ПКМ по `SQL` строке

Шаг 2: `Show Context Actions`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шаг 3: `Inject language or reference`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шаг 4: Выбрать необходимый язык (`SQL`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]